# Application level DateTime value from server with continuous update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have a `WinForm` application in C#. In the `Program.cs` file, I have get my database server time through web API.

Here, I want to access these database server time **with updated value when I access it** across multiple forms for various operations.

**For Instance:** At the point where I get the database server time in the `Program.cs` is: `2017-04-21 13:00:00`. When I access this value in Main form after 120 seconds later... it should be `2017-04-21 13:02:00`.

And, after a 300 seconds later, when I access the same value from another form. It should be `2017-04-21 13:07:00`

Comment: So you basically just need to create a method that take the time it got from the server and compares it to the current time and adds the timespan inbetween to the server time?

Comment: You specifically want the time from the sql server? Use GetDate() in a sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the difference between the local time and DB time. And every time you access current time you should apply that difference:

```
class YourClass
{
    TimeSpan timeDiff;

    public void SetServerTime(DateTime serverTime)
    {
        timeDiff = serverTime - DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime ServerTime => DateTime.Now.Add(timeDiff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. let me try this

Comment: Its working as I expected. But, how to handle if my web api request get delayed for some seconds...? for instance: if my web api request to get database server time: `2017-04-21 13:00:00`. if I get response after some 15 seconds delay... it still the same as `2017-04-21 13:00:00`. but my server time is  `2017-04-21 13:00:15`.

Comment: That's a different question. And you cannot be completely precise here. You can measure what it takes to get a response back. But it still won't be precise.

Comment: Ok. In another case, it produces wrong output when I change my local system time while application is running.. Could you please assist me to handle this situation?

Comment: I think it should be possible to subscribe to some system event, but I have no knowledge in it. Again, that's another question. Try ask a see if someone can help. Or better try to google first.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your effort and its working except above situation. Cheers!!! :)